# Stuck on weird jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, external

Ok, here is my code, it is stored in an external js file, and properly included in the main html in head section.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var checkForConfirmation = function(){
    for(var i=0; i<myOrders.length; i++){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "orderStatus.php",
            data: {action: 'get', id: myOrders[i]},
            success: function(data){
                if (data){
                    var reply = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $("#fancyAlertLink").fancybox().trigger('click');
                    myOrders.splice(myOrders[i], 1);
                }
            }
        });
        if (myorders.length == 0){
            clearInterval(waitForRestourantInterval);
        }
    }
}
if (myOrders.length > 0){
    var waitForRestourantInterval = setInterval(function(){checkForConfirmation()}, 5000);
}
});
```

As you can see, I'm trying to display a fancybox when the back-end script ("orderStatus.php"), gets the right data.

Everything works fine if I don't use jQuery (example: window.alert instead of fancybox), but when I try to use jQuery inside this function, I get a weird error.

Firebug says that there is an error on line `$("#fancyAlertLink").fancybox().trigger('click');`

There is no error description, just"$("

What am I doing wrong???

---

Sorry. I know this is not an answer, but I can't put it all in comment.
Here is the "updated" code.
Error is gone now, but fancybox still will not trigger from my script.

**EDIT:** The trigger doesn't work when inside the success function. I tried to move it outside and it works. The problem is I really need it inside the success. I tried to move the trigger invoke in separate function and call the function from success, but same result. Doesn't work! Any suggestions?

confirmationDaemon.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var checkForConfirmation = function(){
    for(var i=0; i<myOrders.length; i++){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "orderStatus.php",
            data: {action: "get", id: myOrders[i]},
            context: i,
            success: function(data){
                if(data!="null"){
                    var reply = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $("#fancyAlertLink").trigger("click");
                    myOrders.splice(this, 1);
                }
            }
        });
        if (myOrders.length == 0){
            clearInterval(waitForRestourantInterval);
        }
    }
}
if (myOrders.length>0){
    var waitForRestourantInterval = setInterval(function(){checkForConfirmation()}, 5000);
}
});
```

main html file: (smarty+html, smarty {literal} tags ignored in this post)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="fancyBox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myOrders = new Array();
            {foreach from=$smarty.session.my_orders item=id}
                myOrders.push({$id}):
            {/foreach}
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function{
                $("#fancyAlertLink").fancybox();
            });
        </script>
        <script src="confirmationDaemon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        --- some content here ---
        <a id="fancyAlertLink" href="#fancyAlert">Show fancy</a>
        <div style="display:none">
            <div id="fancyAlert">Fancybox hell yeah!!!</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Set intervals and AJAX work as expected. The fancybox shows when I click on the "Show fancy" link. But it doesn't get triggered from the external js. I debugged it. It should work, it executes that line, but nothing appears

Comment: it seems that that line is invalid($("#fancyAlertLink").fancybox().trigger('click');) what is that supposed to do anyway?

Comment: @guildsbounty that is absolutely not true. There's nothing wrong with that line of code.

Comment: What if you call $("#fancyAlertLink").fancybox().trigger('click') from the firebug command line? What if you do something with the $ function that doesn't call .fancybox() ?

Comment: That is how you open a fancybox modal by faking a click, and it looks ok, what if you remove the line above it?

Comment: @ZolaKt can you post what the JSON response looks like?

Comment: @guildsbounty I don't think double quotes are the problem. I have used them in other scripts, and they all work fine

@corroded It is supposed to "bind" fancybox plugin to the #fancyAlertLink (anchor link), and trigger the links onclick event

Comment: The quoting shouldn't be a problem; Are you loading Fancybox _after_ jQuery on your page?

Comment: @Pointy JSON response is just a custom object encoded, not really important. If I remove that line completely the mentioned problem still exists

Comment: @qor72 Yes I'm loading fancybox after jQuery. In the main html file

Answer (score 4):

Here's one problem you're going to have:  when you set up those AJAX calls inside your "for" loop, the code in the "success" handler references the variable "i" that's used for the loop iterations.  That's going to be a big problem, because *all* of the functions will reference the *same* variable "i".  Thus when the functions are actually invoked, asynchronously when the HTTP requests complete, they'll all see the same value of "i" (which will be the *last* value "i" had when the loop ran).

To get around that problem, set up your "success" handlers a little differently:

```
        success: (function(i) {
          return function(data) {
            if (data){
                var reply = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $("#fancyAlertLink").fancybox().trigger('click');
                myOrders.splice(myOrders[i], 1);
            }
          };
        })(i)
```

Doing it like that will ensure that each separate handler has its own copy of "i", and a copy with the correct value.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** There's likely a few problems.

- You're passing `myOrders[i]` to `.splice()`. I assume it doesn't contain an index number like `.splice()` requires.
- The value of `i` problem described below.
- Even with those two problems resolved, you still have an issue because `.splice()` ***modifies*** the Array, so any index number higher than one that was used in the splice is obsolete, because your `.splice()` is ***removing*** items from the Array.

---

You're doing:

```
myOrders.splice(myOrders[i], 1);
```

in a `success:` callback to an asynchronous AJAX call. By the time this code fires, `i` is the same value of `length`, so there's no item at that index.

In other words the last item is `length - 1`, but `i == length` so `myOrders[i] == undefined`.

One simple and efficient fix would be to set `myOrders[i]` as the `context` parameter of the AJAX call.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "orderStatus.php",
        context: myOrders[i],
```

Then in the `success:` callback, `this` will refer to that item.

```
       success: function(data){
            if (data){
                var reply = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $("#fancyAlertLink").fancybox().trigger('click');

                 //  -------------v-----references the proper item
                myOrders.splice( this, 1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: ok, thanks. but i don't think that is causing the error. it has nothing to do with jQuery. when i do a simple windows.alert everything works

Comment: @ZolaKt: But when/where are you doing the alert?

Comment: @ZolaKt well there's absolutely nothing wrong with putting some jQuery function calls in a handler function like that; it's just JavaScript code after all.

Comment: @patrick I want to display fancybox when the back-end function returns some actual values, not just empty string. It is a kind of order notification system

Comment: @ZolaKt: Hang on. What is the value of `myOrders[i]`? Is it an index number? EDIT: ...splice() requires an index for the first parameter. What are you passing it?

Comment: @patrick It is an index number. It's a copy of a PHP $_SESSION variable, which contains an array of "active" order ids.

Comment: @ZolaKt: Yes, but is it an index number that is relevant to the index numbers of the `myOrders` Array?

Comment: @parick No, it is not. myOrders[i] is the order id value. It has nothing to do with the array

Comment: @ZolaKt: Then it is not useful for the `.splice()`. Try just removing that line entirely and see if things work better for you.

Comment: @patrick You are right. I changed the context to "i", instead of "myOrders[i]". The timer and cancellation work fine, but the fancybox still doesn't trigger.

Comment: @ZolaKt: I don't know much about `fancybox` but it seems that the `.fancybox()` method is used to *create* the gallery. Here you're attempting to re-create it with every response that returns. I think you perhaps just want `$("#fancyAlertLink").click();`, although you're still triggering the click several times.

Answer (score 1):

try to trigger the click on the element, e.g `$('#fancyAlertLink').trigger('click');`

Comment: if i take out the whole fancybox() and trigger just the element there are no errors, but no behavior as well

Comment: you should call $('#fancyAlertLink').fancybox() when page loads. after that you can trigger it like I said in the answer, but see answers from Pointy and patrick dw about the `i` issue

Comment: @matei I have tried that. No errors. But it doesn't trigger from external script. Can I use live() with trigger()?

Comment: I have combined your and patricks method, and the intervals and ajax works fine. But the fancybox is still not getting triggered.
Now I get this warning in firebug
Element referenced by ID/NAME in the global scope. Use W3C standard document.getElementById() instead.

Comment: can you post updated code and relevant html ? (the `#fancyAlertLink` element)

Comment: code is my new answer. couldn't get it all to fit into a comment