# jQuery .trigger('click') inside interval function?

Tags: triggers, mouseevent, jquery, setinterval

This is a rephrased question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031019/stuck-on-weird-jquery-error). After some testing I isolated the problem, but have no clue on fixing it. No need to read the previous question, this is the simplified code:

**THE PROBLEM ->** `trigger('click')` executes, but the event doesn't trigger when inside looped (intervaled) function

```
$(document.ready(function(){
    var checkForConfirmation = function(){
        clearInterval(checkInterval);
        $("#anchorLink").trigger('click');
    }
    var checkInterval = setInterval(function(){checkForConfirmation()}, 5000);
});
```

The function is being called in intervals. When the proper response is replied, interval stops, and *simulates* the click on an anchor link.

In the html file there is an anchor link `<a id="anchorLink" href="#hiddenDiv">Show</a>`.
It points to the hidden div which has some content. I'm using Fancybox plugin to show the hidden div when the anchor link is clicked.

If I click on `Show` link fancybox shows, as expected.
If I get the response from the back-end, code executes as expected, but fancybox is not shown.
If I move `$("#anchorLink").trigger('click');` outside the `checkForConfirmation` function, fancybox shows.
When I replace `$("#anchorLink").trigger('click');` with `$("#anchorLink").text('Im clicked');` the string shows in the `<a id="ancoredLink">` tag.

This is the summary, I have tried it in different situations.
The problem is obviously in triggering the *click* event while in looping function. The `$("#anchorLink")` selector is accessible, it is triggering it correctly from everywhere else. Obviously there is a problem in triggering the mouse event inside looping function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't really have anything to do with the problem, but this whole snippet can be shortened to `setTimeout(function () { $("#anchorLink").trigger('click'); }, 5000);`. You're not using the interval at all, you're just replicating a timeout.

Comment: Yes I know. My problem is a little more complex, so I really need the intervals, and not the timeout. See the related question if interested. This is the isolated and simplified code from my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // ...
});
```

instead of:

```
$(document.ready(function(){
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Good catch, but that's apparently just a typo (in this question, not the working code). The previous question has it there correctly.

Comment: @D_N: Its just a typo. Got it right in my code. Thanks for your example. But my code still isn't working. Have you tried opening a fancybox?

Comment: Got it working finally. As you said, the code is fine.
I had another script loaded with ajax which also included jQuery. That was the problem. Thanks for support!