# How to click a button element 3 times periodically per 2 seconds on page load using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I use this code to click a button element (.mybutton) on page load:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
  $('.mybutton').click();
  });
  });
```

and it works pretty fine. What i need is to make it so, that on page load, the button will be clicked 3 times. First click instantly and other 2 clicks with a delay of 2 seconds between them.

I changed my code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
for (var counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) {
$('.mybutton').click();
}
});
});
```

and now the button is clicked 3 times but at the same time. How can i add the delay of 2 seconds between the clicks?

Comment: use javascript setInterval() or setTimeout() functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery .trigger('click') inside interval function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037454/jquery-triggerclick-inside-interval-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var counter = 3
var timer = setInterval(function(){$('.mybutton').click();
counter--
if (counter === 0) clearInterval(timer);

}, 2000);
```